# Visualizing the effect of numerical x_attributes on Categorical y_labels using matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe which has column named as `income` which is in `[range(100,100000)` and another one `smoker` which is boolean as `[Yes,No]`. First is numerical almost different for everyone and second one is categorical. How can I visualize the effect of `income` on the `smoker`.

all of the given from `stripplot, swarmplot` etc produces bad results and `lmplot` works on both the numerical values.

How can I see the effect one on the other using any of matplotlib or seaborn?

Comment: [Barplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)?

Comment: Sorry but link is broken. How can I use Barplot here?

Comment: Hmmm 3.1.2 link not working, [here’s 3.1.1](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)